# Install XP driver on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, drivers

I'm trying to install Intel HD Graphics XP driver on my Windows 7. Of course, for a reason (PAE Patch).
I have downloaded the installer in both .exe and .zip formats but I couldn't run the installer even though I set Compatibility Mode to XP SP3. 
Here are the drivers available to download: http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop+graphics+drivers&ProductProduct=2nd+Generation+Intel%C2%AE+Core%E2%84%A2+Processors+with+Intel%C2%AE+HD+Graphics+3000%2f2000

I also tried adding the driver manually in Device Manager but none of the .inf files were accepted.

The installer says: This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software.

Any suggestion?

Comment: If it's designed for XP then it's not going to work on Win7, I doubt there's much you can do about it.

Comment: There seem to be drivers for Windows 7 as well on the same page. Have you tried them ?

Comment: I've been successful the other way round, but I don't think this is going to work... I don't get it why you downloaded the XP version, and not the Win7...

Comment: You cannot install a Windows XP driver on Windows 7.

Comment: I can. See my answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have managed to install the XP driver by modifying the corresponding .inf file to enable the setup to run on newer version of Windows as well. And it works like a charm. I mean there is no Windows Areo anymore but that's not a problem for me.

Comment: at papaiatis, Posting how you modified the inf file would be very helpful, your answer in the current form is useless to anyone reading this.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Bali C already commented: it is not going to work, as the driver model since Windows Vista ([UMDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-Mode_Driver_Framework)) is completely different to the model used in Windows XP.

> Vista laid the groundwork for a host of new technologies, all
>   absolutely vital to pushing Windows into the 21st century. Vista’s
>   new, modern driver architecture was designed to move core
>   functionality from the kernel (where any instability can bring down
>   the whole system) to user space—an absolutely necessary development.

[[source](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/reviews/windows_7_review)]

That last line effectively describes the cause for the incompatibility.